# Add a request header on mod_proxy based on the value of another request header

Tags: mod-proxy, apache-2.2, requestheader

I have a server running mod_proxy and I need to essentially rename a request header. A proxy closer to the origin is stripping off the X-Forwarded-For header, but we need that data to persist, so I want to add the value to a different header to allow the origin to pick it up.

From my reading of the doco there is no way to rename a header and I can't see how to pass in values into RequestHeader add in mod_headers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RequestHeader` can insert values of environment variables into header values, and `SetEnvIf` can set environment variables based on request header values, so the following configuration should achieve what you need:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For (.*) saved_x_forwarded_for=$1
RequestHeader set X-Custom-Forwarded-For "%{saved_x_forwarded_for}e"
```

You should use `set` instead of `add`, so that even if a client sends a request containing your custom header, the client-specified value will be overwritten (although even this is not 100% reliable, because the `X-Forwarded-For` header could be spoofed too). Also test what happens if a request without `X-Forwarded-For` is received.